# Python pimping / monkey-patching

Tags: python, datetime, python-import

I want to do a simple thing: monkey-patch `datetime`. I can't do that exactly, since `datetime` is a C class.

So I wrote the following code:

```py
from datetime import datetime as _datetime
```

class datetime(_datetime):
    def withTimeAtMidnight(self):
        return self.replace(hour=0, minute=0, second=0, microsecond=0)

This is on a file called datetime.py inside a package I called pimp.

From the error message I'm given:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "run.py", line 1, in 
    from pimp.datetime import datetime
  File "/home/lg/src/project/library/pimp/datetime/datetime.py", line 1, in 
    from datetime import datetime as _datetime
ImportError: cannot import name datetime
```

I assume that I can't have a module called `datetime` importing anything from another module called `datetime`.

How should I proceed to keep my module and class named `datetime`?

Comment: Name you module `datetime2` and when you want to use it import it as `import datetime2 as datetime`?

Comment: That something I would not want to do. I really wanted to call my module datetime.

Comment: Make it `datetime2` and have `from . import datetime2; datetime = datetime2` in `__init__.py`. Then you can `from pimp import datetime` just fine. Name clashes with library modules are still not really nice, however.

Comment: Which version of Python are you using?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Put you module into a package e.g., `your_lib.datetime`. You should not use `datetime` name for a top-level module.

If you are on Python 2 then add at the top:

```
from __future__ import absolute_import
```

to forbid implicit relative imports inside a package. Then if your directory structure is:

```
your_lib/
├── datetime.py
└── __init__.py
```

The following command works:

```
$ python -c 'import your_lib.datetime'
```

where `datetime.py` is:

```
from __future__ import absolute_import
from datetime import timedelta
```

Comment: My module is in a package, ``pimp.datetime``. But it can't import datetime when named as such.

Comment: @LuísGuilherme: You are probably on Python 2. You need to enable absolute imports in this case.

Comment: How would one do this in python 3 then, absolute imports were absolute imports are now the norm ?

Comment: @Carel the code works on Python 3 too (you may omit the `from __future__ ..` there).

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian Oh right, I misread that, shouldn't have been in a rush. Thanks